# Is there a way to make keyboard shortcuts in a browser to navigate to a special web page?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browsing

I was wondering if there is a way to navigate to web pages in a browser( no matter which one this facility is worth being forced to change the browser! ) using keyboard shortcuts for example if I pushed a specific combination of keys then I would be redirected to yahoo or Google!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Firefox by installing [SiteLauncher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10127/) addon.

> SiteLauncher is an add-on for Firefox
>   that gives you a super-quick way to to
>   open your favorite websites using only
>   your keyboard. One special hotkey
>   brings up the 'Launcher', followed by
>   a unique key to launch a site.
>
> Default hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (or
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> for Mac users)

[image]

Comment: thnx but this add-on only shows 100 pages from google search results.does it need any settings to load all of them?

Answer (score 0):

In Safari on the Mac, Cmd-1 through Cmd-9 take you to the first (through ninth) individual bookmark in your bookmarks bar. Multi-item "folders"/menus in the bookmarks bar are skipped. This works even if your bookmarks bar isn't currently showing.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly a keyboard shortcut, but to save on mouse clicks when browsing the web I highly recommend the **free** iMacros browser addons. They are available for [Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/), Chrome and IE. You record a certain browing sequence and can then replay it anytime with a button or mouse click.